# Custom Behavior when Adding New Custom Post Type in Dashboard

Tags: functions, customization, custom-field

I have a Custom Post Type that I'm doing some custom work for. I want to attach some custom functionality to the post type once it's created but an admin can only trigger the custom action from the dashboard.

**For Example**

You create a new Post of the custom type and after it's created you can go to edit the post and in there you see a button that says "Custom Function" which will run some javascript.

**The Idea**

I need the custom button to run a function in functions.php which will create X amount of entries in a custom table on the mysql database and then return the values. I'll use an input next to the button to decide X's value.

I'll be fine with the php + sql + ajax but I just don't know a non-hack way to get the custom inputs to show up on the edit page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Add a meta box](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) to your custom post type edit screen to contain your markup. Check the `$pagenow` global to only show it on `post.php`, not `post-new.php`, and check `$current_user` global for administrator role to exclude other user roles.

Also, if you aren't familiar, check out the [`$wpdb` class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) for your queries, and read up on using [AJAX in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

**EDIT** use `get_current_screen` and `current_user_can` rather than dirty, dirty globals, as @TheDeadMedic suggested in comment below.

Comment: I would advocate `get_current_screen()->id` and `current_user_can( 'cap' )` over globals.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic - you're right, I was thinking meta boxes were added on `admin_init` for some reason, which is too early for `get_current_screen`, but I'm wrong there.